# Sorting rows in PHP/MySQL that match certain criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, lamp

I have a database table with 6 fields that holds information about restaurants:
id
name
type
category_1
category_2
category_3

There are three "types" of restaurants: gold, silver, and bronze.  Gold restaurants are featured on all 3 of their category pages (category_1, category_2, and category_3).  Silver restaurants are featured on their top two categories (category_1 and category_2).  Bronze restaurants are featured on their first category only (category_1). On my category pages, I need to display all restaurants in those categories, but Feature the restaurants who qualify to be featured (ie, they need to be listed at the top). I'm not sure how to do this with PHP / MySQL. I can query restaurants in the categories just fine, but how do I tell it to put Featured restaurants at the top? This is what I would need to do on the category "Mexican":

Display all mexican restaurants. Promote Gold restaurants that have "Mexican" listed in any of their category fields, Promote Silver restaurants that have "Mexican" in their top two category fields, and promote Bronze restaurants that have "Mexican" in it's top category field.

I've been thinking of many different ways to do this and can't figure it out.

Comment: I just can't in good conscience directly address your question, because your table structure is simply wrong.  
Whenever you have columns like 'category_1', 'category_2' etc, this indicates that category is a repeating group and does not belong in the table.  
The proper solution is to fix your structure by "normalizing" out the repeating group into seperate tables.

What you should have is a "categories" table with 1 row for each category.  Then you need a table between restaurant and category to resolve the many to many relationship.

Comment: Often people will name this table something like restaurantcategory.
restaurantcategory will have foreign keys in it for category and restaurant, and possibly a 'roworder' column if it's important to preserve the idea of 1st, 2nd 3rd in some arbitrary way.

Comment: You get benefits from the correct structure:  
-queries for categories don't need to look in all 3 category columns
-you can add a 4th or 5th category at any time without breaking your application
-if categories are strings, by storing a numeric key rather than several large strings you substantially decrease the size of the table
-often the db provides "referential integrity" constraints which will make sure for example, that you can't enter a category for a restaurant that doesn't exist in the category table
-- and... it's just the way relational databases were meant to be designed.

Comment: I'm working with 3rd party software that (CRM for contact management) and this is how they have organized the data. The categories are technically in a different table, but the relationship is stored on the individual contact's (restaurant's) record... Unfortunately I can't change the db structure without breaking the software...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out with your existing table structure. 
I'm assuming `type` contains `bronze`, `silver`, and `gold` in this query.

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants 
WHERE category_1 = 'Mexican' 
  OR (category_2 = 'Mexican' AND type in ('silver','gold'))
  OR (category_3 = 'Mexican' AND type = 'gold')
ORDER BY Field(type,'gold','silver','bronze'), name asc;
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick response, I've been searching for hours on the exact way to "phrase" what I've been trying to do, thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a conception problem. You shouldn't have three "category_X" columns. Instead, you should have a separate table (restaurant_category for instance). Basically, your table structures would look like this :

```
restaurant (restaurant_id, name, type)
restaurant_category (restaurant_id, category_name)
```

You could (and should) even normalize your tables by creating a category table and a type table, but for the sake of this question, I just assume you won't. Then, you add one row in restaurant_category for a bronze restaurant, two for a silver and three for a gold, and you can use a query like this one :

```
    SELECT name
      FROM restaurant
INNER JOIN restaurant_category
     USING (restaurant_id)
     WHERE category_name = 'Mexican'
  ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'); -- if you had normalized
                                                    -- you'd use a column like
                                                    -- type_order to order by
```

Comment: Close to what I suggested but I'd go the extra distance and have a category table for space related performance reasons, and to avoid concerns about typos.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your order by:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(type,"gold","silver","bronze")
```